# XSLT set value-of depending on comparison of different elements

Tags: xslt

OK this is pretty hard to explain but what I need is to set a value-of based on if the current element from one series of nodes matches any of the other elements from another series of nodes. It's probably better illustrated so here goes with a rough example of what I'm asking.
Say I have an xml with the following

```
<Person>
   <name>John Smith</name>
   <id>25</age>
   ....
</Person>
<Person>
    <name>Smith, Will</name>
    <id>22</age>
   ....
</Person>
and so on and so on

<name>
    <given>Smith, Will</given>
    <alternate>Will Smith</alternate>
</name>
<name>
    <given>BobbyJ.</given>
    <alternate>Bobby Johnson</alternate>
</name>
and so on and so on.
```

What I need is if the name from the person i.e Smith, Will appears in any of the given elements from the name to set the value as the alternate element otherwise to as the name from the person. So for example my example would print out

```
John Smith

Will Smith
```

as the resultant.

Hopefully this can be done in XSLT and preferably version 1.0 as it is a safeguard against miswritten values in order to ensure they are in the correct format, note this isn't the example I'm using as the one I am is much more complex with muddled up code that I have inherited, this should be a relevant example that should demonstrate basically what I need and hopefully make it clear for other people. An example of the XSL I'm using if it helps would be

```
<xsl:template match="Person">
    <xsl:variable name="person" select="."/>
    <div class="...">
        <div class="...">
            <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="//name">
                    <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="given = $person/name">
                                <xsl:value-of select="alternate"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
```

That will give me the `alternate` name if necessary but not the `given` name. I need to give the value-of the `name` if it is not in the `name` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="Person">
    <div class="...">
        <div class="...">
            <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="//name[given = current()/name]/alternate">
                <xsl:value-of select="//name[given = current()/name]/alternate"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </div>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Yep that'll do it. Thanks a bunch